# Extract item from cell dictionary in a df column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with a column `messages`, which has a large messy dictionary. I want to extract the title from cell.

```
df["title"] = df["messages"].apply(
                        lambda x: re.search(
                            r"'title': '(.*?)',", str(x)))
```

Output:
`<re.Match object; span=(364, 456), match="'title': 'Creating different tests on glass width.>`

```
df["title"] = df["messages"].apply(
                        lambda x: re.search(
                            r"'title': '(.*?)',", str(x)).group(1)
                    )
```

The follow line gives me an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error.
with the group.

Its because some row contains null values. Not sure how to bypass the issue.

Edit:

```
 df["title"] = df["messages"].apply(
                            lambda x: re.search(
                                r"'title': '(.*?)',", str(x)).group(1) if x else None)
```

messages column:

```
[{'id': '42', 'value': '32', 'state_id': '0', 'state_version': '1', .... 'title': Creating different tests on glass width.', 'preheader_text': 'Could the width effect the colour of the inside material’, …
```

Its not exactly a dictionary, rest of the code has a bunch of html and css scripts. That's why I cannot simply treat it as a dictionary.

Comment: You can add `if x else None` after `re.search()`

Comment: Change the function in the lambda call to `re.search(r"'title': '(.*?)',", str(x)) if x else ''`. In essence if x can be null change it to a empty string.

Comment: or you can change all null values to 0 or something else before running this.

Comment: Adding `if x else None` and similar suggestions in the comments above only work if the cell is empty. Doesn't work if the cell is non-empty and doesn't contain the regex.

Comment: Both ways works without group as before but I want the output to just have the match. Both ways doesn't work when group(1) is added. See Edit.

Comment: @james Provide a sample of what the `messages` column looks like. Is it a JSON string or an actual python dictionary in the column?

Comment: I added a sample row.  @aneroid is right. Some rows doesn't have subject which is why the `group(1)` doesn't work. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the `messages` column contains actual Python dictionaries, then just use the [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method. This has the advantage of providing a default return of `None` if title is missing.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'messages': [{'title': 'title 1', 'field': 'something'},
                                {'title': 'title 2', 'field': 'other'},
                                None,  # None
                                '',  # empty string
                                {'field': 'no title'},
                                {'another field': "'title': 'not a title field', "},
                               ]})

# df is:
                                              messages
0           {'title': 'title 1', 'field': 'something'}
1               {'title': 'title 2', 'field': 'other'}
2                                                 None
3                                                     
4                                {'field': 'no title'}
5  {'another field': ''title': 'not a title field', '}
```

Getting the titles:

```py
df['messages'].apply(lambda x: x.get('title') if x else None)

# output:
0    title 1
1    title 2
2       None
3       None
4       None
5       None
Name: messages, dtype: object
```

---

Also, the regex method you have will fail in certain situations, even with the `if x else None` added on. Such as if the cell is non-empty, non-None and doesn't contain the regex. Consider the `df` setup like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'messages': [{'title': 'title 1', 'field': 'something'},
                                {'title': 'title 2', 'field': 'other'},
                                {'another field': "'title': 'not a title field', "},
                               ]})

# df is:
                                              messages
0           {'title': 'title 1', 'field': 'something'}
1               {'title': 'title 2', 'field': 'other'}
2  {'another field': ''title': 'not a title field', '}
```

Trying the regex:

```py
df["messages"].apply(lambda x: re.search(
    r"'title': '(.*?)',", str(x)).group(1) if x else None)

# output is wrong:
0              title 1
1              title 2
2    not a title field
Name: messages, dtype: object
```